# pyqt4 how to set text from line edit to label on button click

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qlineedit

I am trying to design data input form that will add text to a label when the text is entered into a line edit widget when the ok button is pressed, but the answer is completely eluding me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Set label text from line edit with 
ok click
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.qle = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.qle.move(100, 0)
        sometext = self.qle.text

        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.move(100, 100)
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Ok", self)
        btn.move(30, 100)

        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 200)
        self.show

    def buttonClicked(self, sometext):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.lbl.setText(sometext)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do you get this to work please?

Comment: `self.lbl.setText(self.qle.text())`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this to set text to a label:** `QLabel.setText("string text")`

**Combined with:** `QPushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: func())`

**And get the text in the Line Edit:** `QLineEdit.text()`

So complete code should look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Set label text from line edit with 
ok click
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.qle = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.qle.move(100, 0)
        sometext = self.qle.text

        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.move(100, 100)
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Ok", self)
        btn.move(30, 100)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 200)
        self.show

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    def setLabelText():
        text = qle.text()
        ex.lbl.setText(text)

    ex.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: setLabelText())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can't actually test this code, but it *should* work fine.
Tell me if you have any problems, and please give us a traceback.

You might also want to consider moving to PyQt5.6 (Slightly older than the newest, but it has the QtDesigner built in. A quick google search should find you the right executable installer, it's not on their website anymore. If you can't find it I can send it to you.)

Hope it works, and wish you luck!

**Edit:**
I just thought of a simpler way. Should have just said this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    ex.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: ex.lbl.setText(qle.text()))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have used the answer below, but I will look into this option also thank you

Comment: @iFunction Well in summary my response was to add this to your main function:
`ex.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: ex.lbl.setText(qle.text()))`

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a simplified answer. Did some edits to your code. It works fine, and runs successfully.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.qle = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.qle.move(10, 10)

        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(10, 55,200,20)
        self.lbl.setText("Type Something and Press Ok!")

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Ok", self)
        btn.move(10, 100)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 200)
        self.show

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.lbl.setText(self.qle.text())
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also you QLabel was **invisible** because it was out of your QMainWindow area.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Ahmad Taha, that's perfect, thank you very much for this, it appears I still need to do some learning regarding basic scope of classes, methods and functions. yes, the label being invisible was a school boy error,  I have it in the program I am writing, just had not quite worked out the layout for my test code here.

Comment: You're welcome. Accept this answer if you think it helped you :)